# How to create a subView in Android?

Tags: android

I'm new in android and i have a basic problem: I want to make a **`sub View`** containing 2 buttons, and I want to add this **sub View** in a **Relative Layout**. How can i do this using 100% `xml` files? If i can't do this in *`xml`*, I'm waiting your suggestion. I must absolutely point that I want this separate view, containing 2 buttons. Thank you.

Comment: subView is a concept from iOS, i think in android is called child, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is two `Buttons` inside a `View`, that is inside a `RelativeLayout`, there you have:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewToInject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button01"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To add/inject your `LinearLayout` in an empty `RelativeLayout`, use:

```
LinearLayout viewToInject = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewToInject);
relativeLayout.addView(viewToInject);
```

Comment: Ok, i understand this. But now, how can i inject this view(button1+button2) in another view?

Comment: you have to do that using addView() method. But you can only use it in a ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks man! But i don't understand part with ViewGroup. What must be a ViewGroup there?

Comment: A ViewGroup is a special view that can contain other views (called children.) Basically, a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or FrameLayout is a ViewGroup layout. See more in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

Answer (score 0):

I think he means just a simple view...or you should better point out what the function should be of this "subview". Is it always visible, or do you want to make something like a PopUp-Window or AlertDialog?

Anyway, you can build the layout like joao2fast4u mentioned in pure XML, like you wish. But of course you will never be able to handle the views visibility in non-XML. If you want to make a "PopUp", thats called AlertDialog in Android usually, you need Java-Code.

Please explain your wish first to better help you .-)

The wording "subview" is not used in Android Programming so we really not know what you want.´to ask.

This is what you want, but is basically useless, you get also a hint in Android Studio that one of the layouts srves no purpose.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```